# Automatically rename a tmux window to the current command

Tags: bash, tmux

Is there a way of displaying the currently running command (e.g. for situations where the script runs for days and you wish to retrieve the running parameters) as the tmux window name?

I.e
`$ python train_net.py --lr 50` -> would cause the window name to change to `python train_net.py --lr 50` instantly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For future references:

In `~/.tmux.conf` add:

```
set-option -g status-interval 1
set-option -g automatic-rename on
set-option -g automatic-rename-format "#(ps -f --no-headers --ppid $(tmux display-message -p #{pane_pid}) | awk '{ print substr($0, index($0,$8)) }') "
set-option -g history-limit 3000
```

Then inside a tmux console `ctrl+b :source-file ~/.tmux.conf to reload`

Answer (score 2):

You can change tmux default config file. Usually it is in your home folder: `~/.tmux.conf`. Add following lines to it:

```
set-option -g status-interval 1
set-option -g automatic-rename on
set-option -g automatic-rename-format '#{pane_current_command}'
```

You can change `automatic-rename-format` to any thing you like. `pane_current_command` means the current running command.
Then restart your tmux sessions or: 
`Ctrl+b` then `:source-file ~/.tmux.conf` inside a tmux session to re read tmux config file.

Pay attention that this will automatically rename your tab if you haven't set a name for it manually, if you renamed it manually it won't make change.

Comment: This only changes the name to "python", or "script", is there a way that the flags will be listed in the name as well? (now it's just 10 windows named python :) )

Comment: so there is no solution to have the full command?